# Why does Riemann's prime counting $\Pi_0(x)$ function jump by 1/2 when x is exactly a prime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta

The Riemann prime counting function in question is the following:

\[\Pi_0(x)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{p^k<x}\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{p^k\leq x}\frac{1}{k}\]
So that, for any $x$ where $x$ is exactly a prime raised to $k$, this function will jump by $\frac{1}{2k}$.
His derivation goes like this:
He finds that the logarithm of the zeta function is
\[\log{\zeta(s)}=\sum{p^{-s}}+\frac{1}{2}\sum{p^{-2s}}+\frac{1}{3}\sum{p^{-3s}}+\cdots\]
Which can be rewritten using the following identity
\[p^{-ks}=s\int_{p^k}^{\infty}x^{-s-1}ds\]
as
\[\log{\zeta(s)}=s\int_1^{\infty}\Pi_0(x)x^{-s-1}dx\]
My question now is, how come this function jumps by $\frac{1}{2k}$ at each prime power $k$, it seems like this function would jump by $k$ at each prime power? What am I not getting here?

Here is his paper: 
https://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/People/Riemann/Zeta/EZeta.pdf

Comment: Isn't this straightforward from the definition of $\Pi_0(x)$

Comment: Hint: compute by hand $\Pi_0(4.1)-\Pi_0(3.9)$?

Comment: I meant more like: why is this the definition he finds fits. It seems more like it would jump by 1 at each prime rather than 1/2. So my question is more; why is he using that definition?

Comment: He uses this primarily because of what is coming next when $\log(1-1/p)$ is expanded as $\log(1-1/p) = -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{p^{-n}}{n}$. This comes in handy for a subsequent step that involves mobius inversion.

Comment: But the mobius inversion is only for isolating pi(x) from Pi(x) right? I’m more interested in why it jumps twice by 1/2 rather than once by 1 at each prime

Comment: Your interpretation of what $\Pi_0$ ought to be following the derivation is the more natural one (in this particular derivation). Of course, since we're talking about function values on a set of measure zero, it doesn't matter for the integral formula being valid. I believe this function $\Pi_0$ appears elsewhere in number theory though and in some important contexts arises technically as an average of left/right limits, so authors generally maintain this definition. My memory is hazy though so I don't have references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last expression
\[\frac{\zeta(s)}{s}=\int_0^\infty\Pi(x)x^{-s-1}dx\]
Can be inverted by (a modified) Mellin Inversion:
\[\Pi_0(x)=\int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty} \frac{\zeta(s)}{s}x^{s}dx\]
And the Mellin inversion can be derived from the Fourier transform which famously has plateaus at all discontinuities of a function. Meaning that a function, $f(x)$, will be transformed (as a consequence of the Fourier transform) into
\[f_0(x)=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+\epsilon)+f(x-\epsilon)}{2}\]